# how to configure alpine (pine) to open URL links with firefox?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, email, browser, email-client

In response to [comments](https://askubuntu.com/a/210036/) on running `alpine`, how do I "click" this link from the `alpine` MUA (Mail User Agent) running in `gnome-terminal`?

[image: alpine line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it "just works", `alpine` shows this:

```
Who should attend?
View selected URL "http://em.digium.com/NS00bKn400024hK0gQ00n3F" ?                                                                   
                      Y [Yes]                                     U editURL                                                          
^C Cancel             N No                                        A editApp
```

when the link is higlighted or selected with the arrow keys after pressing `enter`; a response of `Y` opens the link with Firefox for me.

There's likely a configuration in `.pinerc` which can be configured by pressing `M S C` from with `alpine`.  Probably this:

```
  [ Viewer Preferences ]
      [ ]  Enable Message View Address Links                                     
      [ ]  Enable Message View Attachment Links                                  
      [X]  Enable Message View URL Links                                (default)
      [X]  Enable Message View Web Hostname Links                       (default)
```

should be sufficient.